# ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH on Digital Ocean

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, digital-ocean, cloudflare, digital-ocean-spaces

I've just created a space on the Digital Ocean cloud.

To enable CDN, it asks for an SSL.

My domain manager is **Cloudflare**.

I've created a CNAME on the **Cloudflare DNS settings page**.

Then created an origin server SSL certificate and added those keys to the Digital Ocean subdomain settings page.

But I'm getting this error when I'm visiting the URL.

`ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SSL certificate for your original domain then it will work. Don't use a certificate generated by Cloudflare, because that is for something else that Cloudflare side use for to enable strict policy in their side.

Comment: This worked for me. I used ZeroSSL to generate the certificate instead of the Cloudflare origin certificate generator.

Comment: yes, free SSL sites work with some limitations like validity if you need more need to pay for a wildcard SSL certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Submitting the CNAME in App Platform before adding the record in the DO networking tab causes App Platform to register the domain with CloudFlare before it exists. There is a 30 minute TTL on this record then your domain will start working.

However, as a workaround you can remove the custom domain, let your app deploy, then re-add the custom domain and it should start working almost instantly.

Comment: what is this, this leads to completely incorrect way

Comment: The actual problem was with the SSL certificate. Anyway, thank you Charith for your support.